# How to access jar libraries method from java script

Tags: java, javascript, html

I make a simple program to access a method which is defined in my jar library from java script
but it shows nothing when I clicked on the button and my code is:

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD> 
<SCRIPT src="hello.jar"></SCRIPT> 
</HEAD> 
<BODY> 
<INPUT type="button" name="Click Me" value="Click Me" onClick="hello();"> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

hello.jar and test.html are in same directory.

Comment: `.JARs` cannot be used as javascript. You must create a `*.js` file to create javascript functions. [Click to learn how javascript works](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp). `SCRIPT` tags only work for javascript, and JAVA and JAVASCRIPT are two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont realy believe this is possible. Java is interpreted on you server. And javascript by default runs in your browser (if you dont use NODE.js or VertX). The only known possible way to call some java code is to make an HTTP request to your server. Try to check out jax-rs which is the standard to implement restfull webservices in java EE 6 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible, even you cant access normal java class method in javascript, so jar is compressed.so its impossible.you can only access java variable in javascript.

```
var test=<%= java variable%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java and JavaScript has zero (0) relations to each other. Absolutely different technologies. You can't do that.

Comment: what do you mean by zero relation?